# Oracle DDL trigger: how to retrieve more details about the event occurred?

Tags: oracle, ddl-trigger

I want to make an history on an Oracle DB about all the DDL operations which are executed by the time.

I have created a `TABLE` and a `DDL TRIGGER` for do that, in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE AUDIT_DDL (
  D DATE,
  OSUSER VARCHAR2(255),
  CURRENT_USER VARCHAR2(255),
  HOST VARCHAR2(255),
  TERMINAL VARCHAR2(255),
  OWNER VARCHAR2(30),
  TYPE VARCHAR2(30),
  NAME VARCHAR2(30),
  SYSEVENT VARCHAR2(30));

--/   
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AUDIT_DDL_TRG AFTER DDL ON SCHEMA 
BEGIN
  IF (ORA_SYSEVENT='TRUNCATE')
  THEN
    NULL;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO AUDIT_DDL(D, OSUSER,CURRENT_USER,HOST,TERMINAL,OWNER,TYPE,NAME,SYSEVENT)
    VALUES(
      SYSDATE,
      SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','OS_USER') ,
      SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_USER') ,
      SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','HOST') , 
      SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','TERMINAL') ,
      ORA_DICT_OBJ_OWNER,
      ORA_DICT_OBJ_TYPE,
      ORA_DICT_OBJ_NAME,
      ORA_SYSEVENT
    );
  END IF;
END;
/
```

This works perfectly: after each DDL statement, I have a new row in the AUDIT_DDL table.

But I still don't have any information about the exact kind of operation has been made.

For example, the following two statements will produce the same `ALTER` SYSEVENT in the AUDIT_DDL table:

```
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE RENAME COLUMN TEMP TO NEWTEMP;

ALTER TABLE MYTABLE DROP COLUMN NEWTEMP;
```

So, in this way, I can't know what operation has been made rather than a generic `ALTER TABLE`, and I can't even know if the column TEMP has been renamed or dropped from the table MYTABLE!

My question is: how can I retrieve some more information about the event has occurred after the DDL execution (object involved, details, etc...)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check the below:

drop the trigger AUDIT_DDL_TRG

```
drop trigger AUDIT_DDL_TRG
```

create a new column

```
 alter table AUDIT_DDL add statements varchar2(1000);
```

run the trigger again

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AUDIT_DDL_TRG
  AFTER DDL ON SCHEMA

DECLARE
  sql_text ora_name_list_t;
  v_stmt   VARCHAR2(2000);
  n        PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  n := ora_sql_txt(sql_text);
  FOR i IN 1 .. n LOOP
    v_stmt := v_stmt || sql_text(i);
  END LOOP;


v_stmt :=regexp_replace(v_stmt,
                                                   'rename[[:space:]]+.*[[:space:]]+to[[:space:]]+([a-z0-9_]+)',
                                                   '\1',
                                                   1,
                                                   1,
                                                   'i');
  IF (ORA_SYSEVENT = 'TRUNCATE') THEN
    NULL;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO AUDIT_DDL
      (D,
       OSUSER,
       CURRENT_USER,
       HOST,
       TERMINAL,
       OWNER,
       TYPE,
       NAME,
       SYSEVENT,
             statements)
    VALUES
      (SYSDATE,
       SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'OS_USER'),
       SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER'),
       SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'HOST'),
       SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'TERMINAL'),
       ORA_DICT_OBJ_OWNER,
       ORA_DICT_OBJ_TYPE,
       ORA_DICT_OBJ_NAME,
       ORA_SYSEVENT,
             v_stmt);
  END IF;
END;
/
```

do some alters, and youll see the statement

Comment: Fantastic! It stores also the full statement! That's even more than I hoped! :) Thank you very much!